# Oracle forms pre query def_where

Tags: sql, oracle, forms, plsql

I need to set def_where condition I have never used that in forms, so i searched on net and i didnt find near anything that i need.

i have this example :

```
 def_where:=def_where||' and napomena like '''||:ro_dok.dsp_napomena||'%'
  ||:ro_dok.dsp_otpremnica||'%''';
```

and what I need is in one date field ( date_of_input - dd.mm.yyyy ) I need to compare with 2  fields one is month (char) and one is year(number). Day is not important.

```
def_where:=def_where||' and date_of_input like '''||:ro_dok.dsp_month||'%'
  ||:ro_dok.dsp_year||'%''';
```

with this code it doesnt work i can get list of the products from the month or year I enter.

Does someone knows how will i use these two field ( month, year) to compare it with data field .

Comment: You can use `EXTRACT` function to get Month and year out of your date and then do the comparision. See here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date into string using `TO_CHAR()`

```
    def_where:=def_where||' and TO_CHAR(date_of_input,''MMYYYY'') 
 like '''||:ro_dok.dsp_month||'%'
      ||:ro_dok.dsp_year||'%''';
```

Comment: It helped me a bit now i have error in this code probably with quotation marks...

def_where:=def_where||'  TO_CHAR(date_of_input,''MM'') like '''||'to_char(date_of_input,''MM'')=nvl(:DSP_month,to_char(date_of_input,''MM''))'||'%'  ||'to_char(date_of_input,''RRRR'')=nvl(:DSP_year,to_char(date_of_input,''RRRR''))'||'%''';

Can someone check it out please!!!